# mv 'x' and 'y' are the same file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script that moves files from one destination to another and afterwards deletes the files that are older than 7 days.

However, I keep getting this same error:

```
mv: ‘x’ and ‘y’ are the same file
```

This is my command:

```
find /opt/files/ -type f -name '*.csv' -mtime +1 -exec mv {} /opt/files/oldCSVFiles/ \;
find /opt/files/oldCSVFiles/ -type f -name '*.csv' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `find` works recursively. It searches for files inside `/opt/files/oldCSVFiles` too. See `-maxdepth` find option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip those files in folder `/opt/files/oldCSVFiles/`:

```
find /opt/files/ -type f -name '*.csv' -mtime +1 -not -path "/opt/files/oldCSVFiles/*" -exec mv {} /opt/files/oldCSVFiles/ \;
find /opt/files/oldCSVFiles/ -type f -name '*.csv' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```